# How to publish jenkins dashbord (mostly UI part like graph and trends) in email?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

How to publish jenkins dashboard in email? I have created a dashboard for my automation job, now I want to publish these trends and gram in email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins email notification setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197742/jenkins-email-notification-setup)

Comment: I dotn think its duplicate. please read question carefully.